# Indy10 TCP Server Freezing

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy, indy10

I using Indy with C++ Builder XE3. It's perfect system but i have some problems. IdTCPServer works really good but when i have some connections on him and i want to stop server then my application freezed. I try to tell how i do it step by step:
1) Starting application (and server listening)
2) wait for new connections (or simulate it, no difference)
3) when we have 10-15 connections - then try to stop server listening. 
4) when code came to IdTCPServer1->Active = false - application will be frozen

i made little video. Maybe it explain situation much better. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNgTxYbLx8g

And here my code:

OnConnect:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&CritLock);
++ActiveConnections;
SetActiveConnections(ActiveConnections);
LeaveCriticalSection(&CritLock);
```

OnDisconnect:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&CritLock);
--ActiveConnections;
SetActiveConnections(ActiveConnections);
LeaveCriticalSection(&CritLock);
```

StopServer Code:

```
void TForm1::StopServer()
{
    TList *list = IdTCPServer1->Contexts->LockList();
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list->Count; ++i)
        {
            TIdContext *AContext = reinterpret_cast<TIdContext*>(list->Items[i]);
            try
            {
                if (AContext->Connection->Connected())
                {
                    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBuffer->Clear();
                    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteBufferCancel();
                    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteBufferClear();
                    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteBufferClose();
                    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->CloseGracefully();
                    AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (const Exception &e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPServer1->Contexts->UnlockList();
    }
    IdTCPServer1->Contexts->Clear();
    //IdTCPServer1->StopListening();
    IdTCPServer1->Active = false;
}
```

Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of all your `StopServer()` code except for the very last line.  When `TIdTCPServer` is deactivated, it performs all necessary cleanups for you.  **DO NOT DO IT YOURSELF** (especially since you are doing it wrong anyway).

```
void TForm1::StopServer()
{
    IdTCPServer1->Active = false;
}
```

Now, with just that code, if your app is still freezing, then that means you are deadlocking the main thread.  That happens if you call `StopServer()` in the context of the main thread and one of two things are happening in your server code:

1. one of your `TIdTCPServer` event handlers performs a synchronized operation to the main thread (either via `TIdSync` or `TThread::Synchronize()`).
2. one of your `TIdTCPServer` event handlers swallows Indy exceptions and does not allow `TIdTCPServer` to terminate one or more client threads correctly when needed.

Internally, the `TIdTCPServer::Active` property setter closes all active sockets and waits for their respective threads to fully terminate, blocking the calling thread until the property setter exits.  If yoou are deactivating the server in the main thread and one of the server threads performs a sync that the main thread cannot process, or otherwise does not terminate correctly when it should be, that will block the server deactivation from exiting and thus deadlock the main thread.

So make sure that:

1. you are not performing sync operations to the main thread while the server is being deactivated by the main thread.  If you must sync, then deactivate the server in a worker thread instead so the main thread is not blocked anymore.
2. your event handlers are not swallowing any Indy `EIdException`-derived exceptions in `try/catch` blocks.  If you catch such an exception, re-throw it when you are finshed using it.  Let `TIdTCPServer` handle any Indy exceptions so it can perform internal cleanups as needed.

Lastly, on a side note, you do not need to keep track of connections manually.  `TIdTCPServer` already does that for you in the `Contexts` property.  If you need to know how many clients are currently connected at any moment, simply `Lock()` the `Contexts` list, read its `Count` property (or do anything else you need to do with the clients), and then `Unlock()` the list.